# Optimize code for two similar states in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two similar states in React:

```
const [bareLong, setBareLong] = useState([
    ["2", "14"],
    ["1", "16"],
  ]);

  const [bareTrans, setBareTrans] = useState([
    ["2", "14"],
    ["1", "16"],
  ]);

  function addBareLong() {
    setBareLong(function (prevBareLong) {
      const newArr = [...prevBareLong, ["2", "14"]];
      return newArr;
    });
  }

  function addBareTrans() {
    setBareTrans(function (prevBareLong) {
      const newArr = [...prevBareLong, ["2", "14"]];
      return newArr;
    });
  }
```

Functions addBareLong() and addBareTrans() will be added on two buttons.
How can I simplify this code? I think I copy-paste too much.

Comment: This screams 'custom hook'

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in one state
the state is object like

````
const [bareState, setBareState] = useState({
  bareLong: [
    ["2", "14"],
    ["1", "16"]
  ],
  bareTrans: [
    ["2", "14"],
    ["1", "16"]
  ]
});

function addBareLong() {
  setBareState(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      bareLong: [...prevState.bareLong, ["2", "14"]]
    };
  });
}

function addBareTrans() {
  setBareState(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      bareTrans: [...prevState.bareTrans, ["2", "14"]]
    };
  });
}
```
this is the first solution what i prefer or you can use this:
```
function addNewItem(prevState, setState) {
  setState(prevState => [...prevState, ["2", "14"]]);
}

function addBareLong() {
  addNewItem(bareLong, setBareLong);
}

function addBareTrans() {
  addNewItem(bareTrans, setBareTrans);
}
```
````